# Sharepoint 2010 Profile Picture Storage

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have this sharepoint site configured to let the users upload their profile picture to the default image library (http://intranet/my/User%20Photos). When someone right-click on the image and goes to Properties, they have the full URL of the image, where they can get the address to the list with all the users pictures.

My question is, is there a way to mask that URL on the people search result webpart? or is there a way to not let users see the pictures if they access the image library? or is there a way to block the access to the image library without blocking the images from being displayed?

Thanks a bunch.

-- Problem "solved". I edited the default view hiding all the columns. So when a common user access the list, he won't see anything, and he cannot edit the view. Works for now. Thanks.

Comment: Please post this as answer instead of a comment on question :-)

Comment: Be aware that you are not intended to upload pictures to User Photos. This library is intended to be used by SharePoint either when users add a photo to their profile (on Edit Profile from person.aspx) or when User Profile Synchronization adds temporary images for thumbnail generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sharepoint designer you can set the properties of the library to not show in the browser. Then you can create a search exclusion rule so the library won't be crawled.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the link below. This might be helpful.
http://www.andrewshough.com/development/sharepoint/bulk-upload-of-profile-pictures-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks for the link Sepaka, but i got my service running already and it's working fine. I just need to somehow hide the list/files for users accessing the pictures library, or mask the URL so the users can't get to the list.

Comment: unfortunately there are alot of misinformation out there on how to upload photos to user profiles in SP2010. Uploading picture url directly to user profiles will not generate the appropriate thumbnails to User Photos (144px, 96px, 32px) and hence give you problems in Org chart and other places. For a better description on how to set this up check out Todd Carters blog: http://www.todd-carter.com/post/2011/05/02/Grabbing-Your-Pretty-Mug-from-Active-Directory.aspx